# Is there any way to reference the current module in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift4

Let's say I'm writing a swift module, and I want to name a type with a name which already exists.  If the name is from another module, it's easy.  I can just use the module name as a namespace:

```
import Foundation

class MyClass {
    class Notification : Foundation.Notification { ... }
}
```

My question is, is there any way to do the same with types in the same module?  For example, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
class Notification { ... }

class MyClass {
    class Notification : Module.Notification { ... }
}
```

Where `Module.Notification` is a reference to the type declared above.  Is such a thing possible?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? What you wrote is how it works already.

Comment: If I try to run the second block of code in a playground I get: `Use of undeclared type: Module`

Comment: Ah. You need to use the actual name of your module. If you're working in Xcode, that defaults to your target name.

Comment: Ah ok I should have thought of that - works perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the actual name of your module:

```
class Notification { ... }

class MyClass {
    class Notification : MyAmazingTwitterApp.Notification { ... }
}
```

If you're working in Xcode, this defaults to your target name. There's a build setting "Product Module Name", under "Packaging" that lets you change this.

If you're using the Swift build system, this is of course specified in your manifest file, via the `PackageDescription`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the hypothetical use case described in the question with nested structs, something like:

```
struct APIClient {

    struct Account {
    
        func something() -> Account { // <---- problem
        }
    
    }

}
```

when I had somewhere else:

```
struct Account {
    var id: String
    var name: String
}
```

The accepted answer would work very well but in my case the code is shared by multiple targets so I can't reference the module name since it changes based on what I'm building.
An easy alternative that allowed me to stubbornly keep the classes named the same was to just create an alias for that specific method

```
typealias RootAccount = Account

struct APIClient {

    struct Account {
    
        func something() -> RootAccount {
        }
    
    }

}
```